# Mongoose connecting to database but still responding to .catch method after mongoose.connect?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So I am learning the basics of Nodejs and using Mongoose to connect to mongodb. I can successfully connect to database and perform get and post methods on database, but when trying to connect to database, the mongoose.connect method that returns a promise, is working with both .then() and .catch() and I am not sure why, since a promise can either return a resolve or a reject. resolve should call .then() and reject should call .catch()...

Line 16 and the highlighted line in console show my issue. Any guidance is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: For future questions, it is better to paste relevant code and not a screen shot as it is easier for other members to read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not handle the connect promise reject\resolve properly. Try and change your connect code to something like

```
mongoose
  .connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/vidly')
  .then(() => console.log('Connected to Mongoose...'))
  .catch(err => console.error('Could not connect to mongodb'));
```